# Oracle SQL compare strings and find matching sub-strings

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, match

I have colon separated tags associated to two different entities in two tables. Would like to do a sub-string matching for the tags and relate the entities.

```
Table 1 - Table of issues

Issue ---------------- Tag

Issue 1 -------------- Dual UOM:Serial Control:Material Issue

Issue 2 -------------- Validity rule:Effectivity date


Table 2 - Table of Tests


Test ----------------- Tag

Test 1 --------------- Inventory:Outbound:Material Issue

Test 2 --------------- Items:Single UOM

Test 3 --------------- Items:Dual UOM

Test 4 --------------- Recipe:Validity Rule

Test 5 --------------- Formula:Version control:date

Test 6 --------------- Formula:Effectivity date
```

Now, for each issue in table 1, I need to compare its associated tag with the tags in table 2 and find applicable tests.

In above ex,

Issue 1 - Matched tests will be Test 1, Test 3

Issue 2 - Matched tests will be Test 4, Test 5

All the tags associated to the issues and tests will come from a common tag master.

Any help in providing the sql code snippet that would do this sub-string to sub-string matching is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, What have you tried? You will get more answers if you put some code demonstrating your approach.

Comment: The whole point of the relational model is to avoid multi-value fields. I'm not sure why you are using Oracle if you can't define this kind of data in normalised tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option: split issues into rows and compare them to test tags, using the `INSTR` function. Note that letter case must match. If it doesn't (in reality), use `lower` or `upper` function.

Read comments within code (which is split into several parts, to improve readability).

---

Sample data first:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  issues (issue, tag) as
  4    (select 1, 'Dual UOM:Serial Control:Material Issue' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'Validity Rule:Effectivity date'         from dual
  6    ),
  7  tests (test, tag) as
  8    (select 1, 'Inventory:Outbound:Material Issue' from dual union all
  9     select 2, 'Items:Single UOM'                  from dual union all
 10     select 3, 'Items:Dual UOM'                    from dual union all
 11     select 4, 'Recipe:Validity Rule'              from dual union all
 12     select 5, 'Formula:Version control:date'      from dual union all
 13     select 6, 'Formula:Effectivity date'          from dual
 14    ),
```

Split issues into rows (`splitiss`), compare them to test tags (`temp`)

```
 15  -- split issues into rows ...
 16  splitiss as
 17    (select issue,
 18            tag,
 19            regexp_substr(tag, '[^:]+', 1, column_value) val
 20     from issues cross join
 21       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 22                           connect by level <= regexp_count(tag, ':') + 1
 23                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 24    ),
 25  -- ... and now compare them to test tags
 26  temp as
 27    (select i.issue, i.tag issue_tag, i.val, t.test, t.tag test_tag,
 28       instr(t.tag, i.val) ins
 29     from splitiss i cross join tests t
 30    )
```

Return the result:

```
 31  -- return only test tags which match to separate issues (INS > 0)
 32  select t.issue,
 33         t.issue_tag,
 34         listagg(t.test, ', ') within group (order by t.test) matched_tests
 35  from temp t
 36  where t.ins > 0
 37  group by t.issue, t.issue_tag;

     ISSUE ISSUE_TAG                              MATCHED_TESTS
---------- -------------------------------------- --------------------
         1 Dual UOM:Serial Control:Material Issue 1, 3
         2 Validity Rule:Effectivity date         4, 6

SQL>
```

P.S. I believe you posted wrong test tags for issue #2; should be `4, 6`, not `4, 5`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this worked
I did break the tags into rows and then used substr,instr matching.